# Split a .gz file into multiple 1GB compressed(.gz) files

Tags: linux, split

I have a 250GB gzipped file on Linux and I want to split it in 250 1GB files and compress the generated part files on the fly (as soon as one file is generated, it should be compressed).
I tried using this -

```
zcat file.gz | split -b 1G – file.gz.part
```

But this is generating uncompressed file and rightly so. I modified it to look like this, but got an error:

```
zcat file.gz | split -b 1G - file.gz.part | gzip
gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal. Use -f to force compression.
For help, type: gzip -h
```

I also tried this, and it did not throw any error, but did not compress the part file as soon as they are generated. I assume that this will compress each file when the whole split is done (or it may pack all part files and create single gz file once the split completed, I am not sure).

```
zcat file.gz | split -b 1G - file.gz.part && gzip
```

I read [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/598647/how-to-split-a-file-and-compress-directly) that there is a filter option, but my version of split is (GNU coreutils) 8.4, hence the filter is not supported.

```
$ split --version
split (GNU coreutils) 8.4
```

Please advise a suitable way to achieve this, preferably using a one liner code (if possible) or a shell (bash/ksh) script will also work.

Comment: I'd recommend to write your own "split with gzip" variant in some scripting language. Because otherwise you'll have to read through that 250 GB file many times (first determine it's size and then in loop always take one splice and gzip it)

Comment: How important is it that the parts be independently decompress-able? If you simply run `split -b 1G file.gz`, you'll end up with 250 file parts that you can cat together and then decompress.

Answer (score 5):

split supports filter commands. Use this:

```
zcat file.gz | split - -b 1G --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz' file.part.
```

Comment: As I already mentioned in my question, my version of split does not support --filter option.

Comment: ran across same issue using a mac, one resolution would be to install gnu coreutils using
`brew install coreutils`. 
Further discussion of this issue can be seen in [this unix stack exchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283719/232760)

Comment: @KamleshGallani are you able to accomplish this without the --filter option?

Answer (score 1):

it's definitely suboptimal but I tried to write it in bash just for fun ( I haven't actually tested it so there may be some minor mistakes)

```
GB_IN_BLOCKS=`expr 2048 \* 1024`
GB=`expr $GB_IN_BLOCKS \* 512`

COMPLETE_SIZE=`zcat asdf.gz | wc -c`

PARTS=`expr $COMPLETE_SIZE \/ $GB`

for i in `seq 0 $PARTS`
do
  zcat asdf.gz | dd skip=`expr $i \* GB_IN_BLOCKS` count=$GB_IN_BLOCKS |  gzip > asdf.gz.part$i
done
```